# C++ filling multidimensional std::arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, std

To declare a matrix with all of its elements having a certain value, using `std::array` the only way I know to do so looks like the following:

```
std::array<std::array<int, dim_1>, dim_2> matrix;
for (auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it) 
    std::fill(it->begin(), it->end(), number);
```

Is there a better, more concise way?

Comment: Seems short and understandable, so no, I don’t know  any better way, and thank for let us take a look for your usage 

Comment: you can (and should) use range for. Other than that you could create a `constexpr` function if you use this multiple times.

Comment: You could use a range based loop to make it more compact `for (auto & el : matrix) {fill(el.begin(), el.end(), number);} `. But it looks fine to me.

Comment: @GoodDeeds even if std::array uses C arrays in its underlying implementation, I am precisely expecting an answer taking advantage of C++ and STL functionalities to address that, in case it exists. So no, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @StefanKssmr can you complete the line you were writing? If it reduced the code verbosity it would be an improvement already

Comment: @A.Frenzy Changed it above.

Answer (score 3):

```
auto matrix = std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4>();
const auto value = 64;
```

A one-liner:

```
std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [value](auto& column) { std::for_each(column.begin(), column.end(), [value](auto& element) {element = value; }); });
```

Another one:

```
std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [value](auto& column) { std::fill(column.begin(), column.end(), value); });
```

Something actually readable:

```
for (auto& column : matrix) {
    for (auto& element : column) {
        element = value;
    }
}
```

I have no idea if those are actually columns though

This compiles on latest MSVC too and looks funny enough:

```
std::fill(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), std::array{ value, value, value, value });
```

Comment: for the one liner `error: variable 'value' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified`. I think the lambda function misses an input

Comment: Oh, right. Totally forgot about it, Intel C++ just compiles everything even if its nonsense.

Comment: Write `[value](auto& column){...}` to capture value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for conciseness, you can fill it with a filled array:

```
decltype(matrix[0]) temp;
temp.fill(5);
matrix.fill(temp);
```

You can technically remove the temporary assuming a non-zero dimension:

```
matrix[0].fill(5);
matrix.fill(matrix[0]);
```

In order for this to perform as well as filling in place, you'll have to rely on the compiler seeing through it. Alternatively, you can plop this in a `constexpr` function since C++20 and guarantee a compile-time result if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

With helper function:

```
namespace detail
{

    template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    make_array(const T& value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), value)...}};
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& value)
{
    return detail::make_array(value, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

And then

```
/*const*/ auto matrix = make_array<dim_2>(make_array<dim_1>(value));
```

Advantage over `fill` is that it support non-default constructible types.

And advantage of helper function (even if implemented with `std::fill`) over assignation afterward is that you can initialize `const` variable :)